# JSON field filtering query in MySQL？

Tags: php, mysql

I now have a data table with the following fields: ID, home, away, status。
JSON data is stored in the home and away fields

| id | home | away | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"id":10, "value":0}` | `{"id":11, "value":0}` | 3 |
| 2 | `{"id":11, "value":0}` | `{"id":10, "value":0}` | 3 |
| 3 | `{"id":10, "value":0}` | `{"id":20, "value":0}` | 3 |
| 4 | `{"id":40, "value":0}` | `{"id":10, "value":0}` | 2 |

Now I can use the following statement to query the expected data. 
If I want to filter out the data with ID 11 in home and away during query, how can I modify the SQL?

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table_name 
WHERE 
    status = '3' 
    AND JSON_EXTRACT( home, '$.id' ) = 10 
    OR JSON_EXTRACT( away, '$.id' ) = 10 
ORDER BY 
    id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

**Expected data:**

| id | home | away | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | `{"id":10, "value":0}` | `{"id":20, "value":0}` | 3 |

Comment: change your id value and try

Comment: @KayesFahim Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your query refers to non-existing column `status_id`, because it's `status`

Comment: @Justinas I have just corrected this mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two more restrictions into WHERE clause:

Return only rows with status equal to 3, and home->id or away->id equal to 10 and home->id not equal to 11 and away->id not equal to 11.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    status = '3' 
    AND (home->"$.id" = 10 OR away->"$.id" = 10)
    AND home->"$.id" != 11 
    AND away->"$.id" != 11
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Be careful with the use of AND and OR in WHERE clauses: this `status = '3' AND home->"$.id" = 10 OR away->"$.id" = 10` is like `(status = '3' AND home->"$.id" = 10) OR away->"$.id" = 10` not like `status = '3' AND (home->"$.id" = 10 OR away->"$.id" = 10)`. Sometime you need to use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `JSON_CONTAINS` function as approach:

```
select * 
from tbl
where 
    status = 3 and 
    not json_contains(home, '11', '$.id') and 
    not json_contains(away, '11', '$.id');
```

[Test MySQL query here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=6e5345d20fac3bf337e3b28373fdb21d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)